# Cover entire modal with an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, materialize

I am using Materialize CSS. I have a modal, and I want to set the entire background to an image (so when it opens it looks like you're just viewing an image nice and big with background of the web page blurred). The problem is that when I do this, the image gets repeated if the modal is bigger than it.[image]

I want the image to just stretch over the entire modal.

My modal:

```
<div id="imageModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#imageModal{
  background-image: url("../images/office2.jpg");
  background-reapeat: "none";
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had some typo with background-repeat. Try this:

```
#imageModal{
  background-image: url("../images/office2.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also, if you're using CSS3, you can set the `background-size` property to `cover` so it will help resize your image according to the size of your modal. Like this:

```
#imageModal{
  background-image: url("../images/office2.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi add in your Style ...

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

just inspect and check the style which u have  background-repeat: none which is strikeout already becz there is no style like that so just replace the above one

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
#imageModal{
  background-image: url("../images/office2.jpg");
  background-reapeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Reference here

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/